# Save user inputs from a gui without closing the gui

Tags: autohotkey

Currently, I have the following code that works, the gui just closes and the application crashes afterwards, makes it not flow well.

```
IfNotExist,settings\Defaults.ini
    {
        Gui, Add, Text,, Set the default header:
        Gui, Add, Edit, v1 ym, Enter Text Here
        Gui, Add, Button, default, Submit
        Gui, Show,, Defaults Setup By Altify
        return
        ButtonSubmit:
        Gui, Submit
        IniWrite, %1%,settings\Defaults.ini, Section1, Key
    }
ExitApp
```

Any insight on the matter is helpful

Thanks, Altify

Answer (score 0):

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Submit

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm

Use "NoHide" parameter(gui, Submit, NoHide) and your code is crashing, because it's need a "return" below IniWrite, because, ButtonSubmit is a subroutine.